# Comparing two items: How does 「...と...とどちらが」work?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-と, comparison

I've seen the pattern 「...と...とどちらが」when comparing two items, but I'm unclear how it works. Here's an example: 肉と魚とどちらが好きですか。"Which do you prefer, meat or fish?"

I'm unclear what the second と after 魚 is doing. I know you can include a と after BOTH items when you're listing two items with "and", but then it seems like that 「肉と魚と」 is just floating in space. Since this is a standard polite sentence and not a casual conversational one, it seems like some other particle like は, or even just a comma (indicating an omitted は) should be there.

Or, is that second と supposed to be the "target of comparison" と, the same one used in ...と同じ or ...と違う?

What's the grammar breakdown of this common phrasing, especially for the second と?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8/#jn-154670), it is not the と meaning *and* (格助詞), but a particle of another category 並列助詞. It is a marker for enumeration.

> ［並助］いくつかの事柄を列挙する意を表す。「君―ぼく―の仲」
> 「幸ひの、なき―ある―は」〈源・玉鬘〉

Note that [weblio](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8) lists it as a 格助詞 and 並列 is a usage. So the category is a matter of opinions.

Either way, both と are more like commas and different from と in と同じ/違う.

Comment: That reflects in my question about "肉と魚と just floating in space".  So would it be reasonable to say 「すしとてんぷらと食べています」? It's weird to me how throwing in a second と just eliminates the need for other case particles (格助詞). Correct me if I'm missing some obvious detail here

Comment: @Hikonyan すしとてんぷらと**を**食べています is ok. Re 肉と魚と, it **is** floating, just like *which do you like better, **meat or fish**?* Syntactically *which do you like better* is a complete sentence.

Comment: I see... the comparison to the English sentence makes sense. So my conclusion is that 肉と魚と IS in fact floating in space, and the second と meaning "and" is just included out of convention - even though usually a second と isn't used when listing two items.