# I don't understand this sentence: 人々は、愛情と尊敬と、人間を超えた才能を持った人という気持ちを込めて、手塚治虫を「マンガの神様」と呼ぶ

Tags: sentence

> 人々は、愛情と尊敬と、人間を超えた才能を持った人という気持ちを込めて、手塚治虫を「マンガの神様」と呼ぶ。

So, I have some questions about this sentence:

a) What does the structure nounとnounと mean, and how does it relate to the rest of the sentence?

b) Why are 超える and 持つ in the past?

c) I don't understand the use of という in this situation.

Comment: I'd suggest thinking of 持つ and 超える in this context as momentary or instantaneous verbs: more like "become" (describing the moment or instant that something comes into being), and less like "be" (describing the ongoing state of something).  As such, to use these verbs in a way that describes a state, you'd have to use them in the past tense -- or more specifically, in the completed aspect.  Consider English _surpass_, for instance -- 人間を超えた才能 could be rendered as _"talent that **has surpassed** regular human levels"_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) と can be used for enumeration. Cf. [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/96904/45489). In this case, (an interpretation is) it combines objects for 込める. That is, を込めて is taking three objects (1)愛情, (2)尊敬, and (3)人間を超えた才能を持った人という気持ち.

(b) As Eiríkr Útlendi commented, you can think of the た indicating perfect aspect. Another factor may be that Osamu Tezuka is no longer alive.

If there were a copula,

- 人間を超えた才能を持った人だった
- 人間を超える才能を持つ人だった

would both be fine, but here there is no copula and using present tense sounds odd.

(c) という generally is like *that* which encapsulates the preceding sentence to make a clause. Here it makes a noun modifying clause for 気持ち: the feeling that he was a man with superhuman talents.

Answer (score 0):

The past tenses 超えた＝超えている and 持った＝持っている it's just a grammar point, it is just describing features of things:

人間を超えた才能を持った人という気持ちを込めて、...

人間を超えている才能を持っている人という気持ちを込めます- He is a person with talent that transcends humans, that is the feelings they have for him ( they put into him)。

https://maggiesensei.com/2020/09/08/%E3%80%9C%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%EF%BC%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-wo-shita-shiteiru-describing-ones-featuresshapescolor/

Comment: Could you summarize this grammar point? Otherwise this is a link-only answer and should better be left as a comment.

Comment: https://maggiesensei.com/2020/09/08/%E3%80%9C%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%EF%BC%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-wo-shita-shiteiru-describing-ones-featuresshapescolor/